# concatの使い方について。（pandasのappendでやっている作業をconcatに置き換えたい）

Tags: python, pandas

データフレームに関する作業をしていたら、
　FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
というのがでたので、concatに変えた方がよいのかなと思っていますが、使い方が理解できませんでした。

［作業］
２つのデータフレーム、df_bbase、df_newを用意します。前者は初期状態で値を持ちますが、後者は初期状態では空です。

```
df_base
         ,   key1,   key2,   key3,   key4,   key5
    name1, data00, data01, data02, data03, data04, 
    name2, data10, data11, data12, data13, data14, 
    name3, data20, data21, data22, data23, data24, 
    name4, data30, data31, data32, data33, data34, 
    name5, data40, data41, data42, data43, data44,
```

から、条件に合ったものを抜き出して、例えば、

```
df_new
         ,   key1,   key2,   key3,   key4,   key5
    name1, data00, data01, data02, data03, data04, 
    name2, data10, data11, data12, data13, data14, 
    name5, data40, data41, data42, data43, data44,
```

というものを作りたいと思っています。そこで、

```
for index, item in df_base.iterrows():
    if r'keyword' in item['key2'][0]:     #完全一致ではない条件判定
        df_new = df_new.append(item)
```

というようなことをやると、df_newのような結果が得られ、目的は達成できるのですが、エラーは出ないものの冒頭のようなメッセージが出てきます。それならばと思って

```
for index, item in df_base.iterrows():
    if r'keyword' in item['key2'][0]:
        df_new = pd.concat([df_new, item])
```

というふうにやると、上記、df_newのようにはならず、

```
,key1, key2, key5
key1,,,data00
key2,,,data01
key5,,,data04
key1,,,data10
key2,,,data11
key5,,,data14
key1,,,data40
key2,,,data41
key5,,,data44
```

という感じになってしまいます。

concatはどういう使い方をしたらよいですか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 例えば print(df_base ['keyword']) とをやると、
>
> ```py
>         key2
> name1 [DATA1]
> name2 [DATA2]
> name3 [DATA3]
> ```
>
> になっていて、それぞれがどうも要素数１のリスト形式になっているようなのです。

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

csv_data = '''
,key1,key2,key3,key4,key5
name1,data00,keyword1,data02,data03,data04
name2,data10,keyword2,data12,data13,data14
name3,data20,data21,data22,data23,data24
name4,data30,data31,data32,data33,data34
name5,data40,keyword5,data42,data43,data44
'''
df_base = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data), index_col=[0])

#
df_base = df_base.applymap(lambda x: [x])
df_new = df_base[df_base['key2'].str[0].str.contains('keyword')]

print('df_base:\n', df_base)
print('\ndf_new:\n', df_new)

#
df_base:
           key1        key2      key3      key4      key5
name1  [data00]  [keyword1]  [data02]  [data03]  [data04]
name2  [data10]  [keyword2]  [data12]  [data13]  [data14]
name3  [data20]    [data21]  [data22]  [data23]  [data24]
name4  [data30]    [data31]  [data32]  [data33]  [data34]
name5  [data40]  [keyword5]  [data42]  [data43]  [data44]

df_new:
           key1        key2      key3      key4      key5
name1  [data00]  [keyword1]  [data02]  [data03]  [data04]
name2  [data10]  [keyword2]  [data12]  [data13]  [data14]
name5  [data40]  [keyword5]  [data42]  [data43]  [data44]
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

実はcontainsは試したのですが、エラーが出てが使えないのです。
人からもらったデーなので、なぜこうなっているのかはよくわからないのですが、例えば
print(df_base ['keyword'])

とをやると、
         'key2'
name1 [DATA1]
name2 [DATA2]
name3 [DATA3]

になっていて、それぞれがどうも要素数１のリスト形式になっているようなのです。

例１
df_new = df_base[df_base['key2'][0].str.contains('keyword')

例２
df_new = (df_base[df_base['key2'][0]).str.contains('keyword')

例３
df_new = (df_base[df_base['key2'])[0].str.contains('keyword')

というようなことをやるとエラーが出て実行できません。

Comment: 回答を修正しました。

Comment: ありがとうございました。